# How to configure Azure AD OAuth2 using node-adal and OWIN?

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, owin, adal

How can I configure the OWIN to authenticate an accesstoken request that was collected from Azure AD using node-adal?

**Startup class below:**

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
  {
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    AllowedAudiences = new []
    {
      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"] // AAD clientid from registered application
    },
    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
    {
      new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Issuer"], // https://sts.windows.net/<tenantid-guid>/ retrieved from AAD federationmetadata.xml
        TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"]) // AAD secret from registered application
      )
    }
  });
```

**Token response from node-adal below:**
[implementation described here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-node#authorization-code)

```
{
  tokenType: "Bearer",
  expiresIn: 3599,
  expiresOn: "2016-10-19T13:49:47.649Z",
  resource: "spn:00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  accessToken: "removed for brevity", 
  refreshToken: "removed for brevity",
  userId: "user@domain.com",
  isUserIdDisplayable: true,
  familyName: "familyName",
  givenName: "givenName",
  identityProvider: "live.com",
  oid: "oid-guid",
  tenantId: "tenantid-guid"
}
```

The `accesstoken` from the above node-adal response is sent using

```
Authorization: Bearer accesstoken-here
```

to a secured endpoint using an `[Authorize]` attribute which returns

```
{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

**EDIT to show old and new approach's, old works - new does not**

```
  // this is new version (using clientsecret, aka AD web app)
  var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Issuer"];
  var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"]);
  app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
  {
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    AuthenticationType = OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(),
    AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(
      new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"] }, 
      new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[] { new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret) }
    )
  });

  // this is old version (not using clientsecret, aka AD native app), this works but all my code is in the Angular Single Page app, I am trying to move the auth code into the node server to secure all access
  app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
  {
    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
      ValidAudiences = new[]
      {
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AudienceImplicit"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AudienceDaemon"]
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a specific OWIN middleware for validating tokens from Azure AD:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
        Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],

    }
);
```

Check out the .NET samples at aka.ms/aaddev for more thorough guidance.

Comment: My understanding is that this approach is for the implicit OAuth flow, which I had working but now want to use an id and secret, whereas implicit OAuth does not require secret. Also node-adal does not have code that supports implicit OAuth flow.

Comment: The middleware you choose to use to validate tokens shouldn't depend on how the token was required.

Comment: OK, so I have tried the method you have suggested, which also previously worked for the implicit OAuth grant flow. I retreived the audience from the decoded token and it still shows me a 401. Is there anyway I can debug the internals of the middleware without including the cloned source?

Comment: I have it working - although not completely against multi-tenancy. I can receive AD bearer token but it is not being authenticated in the middleware, which I am sure is just some configuration to be done. Thanks

Comment: Great. No, debugging 401s from OWIN is difficult. I usually end up turning on logging, and if that doesn't help, downloading the source.

Comment: There is a nice multitenant web api code sample available at aka.ms/azure-samples which does exactly this scenario

Comment: Yep, downloaded the source and mutlitenant is now working - a simple configuration issue around issuer.

Comment: The answer does not apply to .net core